# Kernel of RKHS on subspace.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $K$ be a kernel function on $X$. For $x ∈ X$, define $K_x(·) = K(·, x)$. Let $M $ be
the set of all functions on $X $ that can be written as a combination of functions in $\{K_x : x ∈ X\}.$
Suppose $f =\sum_{
finite sum \hskip 0.1 in x \in X} \hskip 0.1 in a_xK_x $and $g =\sum_{
finite sum \hskip 0.1 in y \in X} \hskip 0.1 in b_yK_y $ are two functions in $M$. Note that
such presentations may not be unique. Define
$\langle f, g \rangle$ $=\sum_{
finite sum \hskip 0.1 inx,y∈X}
a_x \bar b_y K(y, x).$

(a) Show that $\langle f, g \rangle$ well-define. That is, it is independent of the representations of $f$ and $g$.

(b) For each $x \in X$ and $f \in M$, show that
f(x) =$\langle f, K_x \rangle_M$

(c) Show that $\langle f, g \rangle$ is an inner product on M and for each x ∈ X, show that there exists a constant
$C_x > 0$ such that for all $f ∈ M$,
$|f(x)| ≤ C_x||f||_M.$

Mostly I'm confused for (a) and (c).If I know what is to show then hopefully I can do rest and for (c) I am not able to prove first property of inner product.

Every help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's the definition of a kernel function? Is symmetry and some kind of positive-definiteness condition included in that?

Comment: This all I have.

Comment: No lecture notes, no definitions, nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a). Let $x_1, \dots , x_n, x_1', \dots , x_k'$ and $a_1, \dots, a_n, a_1', \dots, a_n'$ such that $f=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i K_{x_i}=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i' K_{x'_i}$ as well as $y_1, \dots, y_m$ and $b_1,\dots, b_m$ such that $g=\sum_{j=1}^m b_j K_{y_j}$.

We need to show that $\langle f,g \rangle$ is independent of the choice of the representation of $f$, i.e.

$$\sum_{i=1\dots n, j=1,\dots m}a_i \overline b_j K(x_i,y_j) = \sum_{i=1\dots k, j=1,\dots m}a'_i \overline b_j K(x'_i,y_j).$$

The left hand side is equal to $\sum_{j=1}^m \overline b_j f(y_j)$, using the first identity for $f$. And the r.h.s. is also equal to $\sum_{j=1}^m \overline b_j f(y_j)$, using the second identity for $f$. For $g$, we get the same result analogously.

Comment: Okay I got it. How about (c)?

Comment: (c) can only be solved if we know that $K$ is positive definite. Have a look at http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~sejdinov/teaching/atml14/Theory_2014.pdf and their approach to the moore-aronszajn theorem.

Comment: ya ya K is positive definite